# ASP MVC WEB Api JS table

Tags: jqgrid, datatables, asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm looking to use DataTables.net or jqGrid with an ASP MVC4 ApiController action for the source.

The problem I have is that i just return an array of objects..
e.g. 
[{"Name":"Brian", "Age" : "35"}, {"Name":"Jim", "Age" : "45"}]

I don't format it like the samples i.e. with aaData or arrays of string.
Can anyone tell me how they overcome this problem?

I'll even settle for jqGrid if someone and point me in the direction of a good example.
tnx
Brian.

Answer (score 2):

It' not a problem in jqGrid. You need just define [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data) which describe how the data can be read by jqGrid. For example

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user1127858.htm):

[image]

It uses

```js
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    id: "Name",
    root:  function (obj) {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

and the JSON data which you posted.

Answer (score 0):

To use different actions(Post, Put and Delete) of ASP.NET Web API for add edit delete operations, check following example:
http://techbrij.com/1017/add-edit-delete-jqgrid-asp-net-web-api